# Como extrair um atributo do tipo totalcross.util.Date de um JSON

Tags: totalcross

Estou utilizando um webservice que me retorna uma lista de um Objeto em JSON, e estou tentando utilizar o JSONFactory para extrair as informações do JSON para uma Lista.

```
HttpStream httpStream = new HttpStream(new URI(VarGlobais.url + "/descarga/listDescarga"), options);

    if (httpStream.isOk()) {

        byte[] BUFF = new byte[2048];
        int read = httpStream.readBytes(BUFF, 0, BUFF.length);
        String firstBytes = new String(BUFF, 0, read);

        List<Descarga> listDescarga = JSONFactory.asList(firstBytes, Descarga.class);

        [...]
    }
```

A classe Descarga possui os seguintes atributos

```
import totalcross.util.Date;

[...]

private Integer seqDescarga;
private Integer cdEmpresa;
private Integer cdFilial;
private String placa;
private String siglaUfPlaca;
private Date dtEntrada;
private String hrEntrada;

[GETS / SETS]
```

O webservice me retorna um JSON com os atributos da classe, e a data está no formato YYYY-MM-DD... Quando é executado a linha do JSONFactory.asList(...) dá o seguinte erro:

```
GRAVE: null
totalcross.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 1 line 0]
```

Debugando a variável firstBytes contem o seguinte valor:

```
{"seqDescarga":5456,"cdEmpresa":1,"cdFilial":28,"placa":"EPE3821","siglaUfPlaca":"SP","dtEntrada":"2017-06-09","hrEntrada":"170132"}
```

O problema está no dtEntrada... Por ser do tipo totalcross.util.Date, está dando a impressão que o JSONFactory não consegue converter. Alguém teve esse problema? Encontraram alguma solução para isso?

Comment: Tem mais stack trace?

Comment: Deivison, na edição da minha resposta coloquei um detector de erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A classe `totalcross.json.JSONFactory` interpreta setters de dados rasos e objetos profundos com construtor padrão.

O que seria um dado rasos? São dados que não possuem dados internamente.

E objeto profundo? Objeto que possuo atributos internamente.

## Quais são os dados rasos reconhecidos?

Os primitivos e seus *wrappers* são reconhecidos. Além deles, objetos do tipo `String` também são considerados rasos. Segue a lista dos tipos:

- `int`
- `boolean`
- `long`
- `double`
- `java.lang.Integer`
- `java.lang.Boolean`
- `java.lang.Long`
- `java.lang.Double`
- `java.lang.String`

## Lidando com objetos profundos

Para o TotalCross conseguir usar adequadamente um objeto profundo, ele precisa ter `setters`, que nem o objeto sendo produzido. O `JSONFactory` vai interpretar que objetos profundos são mapeados como objetos JSON também. Por exemplo, poderíamos ter a seguinte estrutura:

```
class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    
    // getter/setter
}

class Carro {
    private String placa;
    private String modelo;

    private Pessoa motorista;

    //getters/setters
}
```

O TotalCross iria conseguir interpretar o seguinte JSON enviado como sendo da classe `Carro`:

```
{
    'placa' : 'ABC1234',
    'model' : 'fusca',
    'motorista': {
         'nome' : 'Jefferson'
    }
}
```

O seguinte JSON iria falhar, pois o TotalCross não entende que o objeto `Pessoa` só tem um único atributo string:

```
{
    'placa' : 'ABC1234',
    'model' : 'fusca',
    'motorista': 'Jefferson'
}
```

Isso lançaria uma exceção com a seguinte mensagem:

> JSONObject[motorista] is not a JSONObject.

Como a classe `totalcross.util.Date` não se encaixa no entendimento de **objeto profundo** (não possui setters com os nomes dos atributos), não é possível utilizá-la no `JSONFactory`. *Mas há alternativas!*

## Contornando a situação

Existem algumas alternativas para contornar esses problemas. As que eu consigo imaginar facilmente agora são:

- DTO
- setter *artificial*
- compilador de JSON próprio

### DTO

A estratégia seria construir um DTO equivalente do objeto e, também, um método que transformaria o DTO no seu objeto de negócio:

```
// classe do DTO apenas com dados rasos
class DescargaDTO {
    private Integer seqDescarga;
    private Integer cdEmpresa;
    private Integer cdFilial;
    private String placa;
    private String siglaUfPlaca;
    private String dtEntrada;
    private String hrEntrada;

    // getters/setters
}

// método que transforma o DTO no objeto desejado
public static Descarga dto2Descarga(DescargaDTO dto) {
    if (dto == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Descarga descarga = new Descarga();

    descarga.setSeqDescarga(dto.getSeqDescarga());
    descarga.setPlaca(dto.getPlaca());
        // ... demais campos rasos ...

    try {
        descarga.setDtEntrada(new Date(dto.getDtEntrega(), totalcross.sys.Settings.DATE_YMD));
    } catch (InvalidDateException e) {
        // tratar formato de data inválida do jeito desejado; pode até ser lançando a exceção para o chamador deste método tratar
    }

    return descarga;
}
```

Esse esquema de DTO eu considero o menos invasivo, em que não exige mudança na sua classe de negócio.

### Setter artificial

Esta estratégia exige alteração na classe de negócio, portanto é mais invasivo do que o anterior. A intenção aqui seria ter um `setCampoJson(String campoJson)` para um campo `campoJson`. Podemos implementar isso de duas maneiras:

1. mudar o nome do campo de JSON de `dtEntrada` para outro nome, como `dtEntradaStr`, e adicionar o método `setDtEntradaStr(String dtEntradaStr)`;
2. mudar o setter `setDtEntrada(Date dtEntrada)` para receber como parâmetro uma String `setDtEntrada(String dtEntradaStr)`.

A primeira alternativa exige uma mudança na serialização do objeto, onde ele não mandaria mais o campo como `dtEntrada`, mas como `dtEntradaStr`.

Particularmente, eu acho a segunda alternativa (mudar o setter para receber outro parâmetro) ainda mais invasivo.

Para a estratégia de adicionar um novo setter de String, a classe `Descarga` ficaria assim:

```
class Descarga {
    private Integer seqDescarga;
    private Integer cdEmpresa;
    private Integer cdFilial;
    private String placa;
    private String siglaUfPlaca;
    private Date dtEntrada;
    private String hrEntrada;

    // getters/setters reais

    public void setDtEntradaStr(String dtEntradaStr) {
        setDtEntrada(new Date(dtEntradaStr, totalcross.sys.Settings.DATE_YMD)); // TODO tratar a exceção possivelmente lançada pelo construtor, seja com try-catch ou lançando a exceção para o chamador
    }
}
```

Na opção de mudar o parâmetro do setter `setDtEntrada` para String:

```
class Descarga {
    private Integer seqDescarga;
    private Integer cdEmpresa;
    private Integer cdFilial;
    private String placa;
    private String siglaUfPlaca;
    private Date dtEntrada;
    private String hrEntrada;

    // getters/setters para todos os atributos EXCETO dtEntrada

    public void setDtEntrada(String dtEntradaStr) {
        dtEntrada = new Date(dtEntradaStr, totalcross.sys.Settings.DATE_YMD); // TODO tratar a exceção possivelmente lançada pelo construtor, seja com try-catch ou lançando a exceção para o chamador
    }

    public Date getDtEntrada() {
        return dtEntrada;
    }
}
```

### Compilador de JSON próprio

Essa alternativa envolve mais esforço. Bem mais esforço, na verdade. A vantagem desse daqui é que você pode usar uma estratégia diferente da DOM. O pacote `totalcross.json` usar a estratégia DOM para interpretar os JSONs.

A estratégia DOM é montar toda a árvore de informação para, depois, passar para alguém interpretar. A class `JSONFactory` trabalha assim.

Uma estratégia alternativa ao DOM é a alternativa [SAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_API_for_XML). A alternativa SAX permite interpretar o conjunto de dados como uma *stream*, não **precisando** montar o objeto inteiro.

Um framework para tratar JSON numa estratégia SAX é o [JSON-Simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple). Fizemos um port significativa do JSON-Simple para dentro do TotalCross, as classes continuam inclusive com os mesmos pacotes =)

Para compilar de modo SAX, implemente a interface [`ContentHandler`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/ContentHandler.java) e chamá-la no método [`JSONParser.parse(Reader in, ContentHandler contentHandler)`](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple/blob/master/src/main/java/org/json/simple/parser/JSONParser.java#L311).

Para transformar a `HttpStream` em um `Reader`, faça assim:

```
public void exemploParseJson(HttpStream stream) java.io.IOException, org.json.simple.parser.ParseException {
    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(stream.asInputStream(), getMyContentHandler());
}
```

Temos um exemplo de `ContentHandler` [aqui](https://github.com/TotalCross/totalcross-big-file/blob/master/src/main/java/com/totalcross/sample/bigfile/ui/JsonSimpleShower.java#L54).

> ## Update

### Detecção do caracter de erro

Hipoteticamente, talvez esteja lendo mais bytes do que apenas o JSON. Para depuração, podemos fazer o seguinte teste:

```
static class JsonTokenerTest extends JSONTokener {
    
    public JsonTokenerTest(String s) {
        super(s);
    }

    @Override
    public JSONException syntaxError(String message) {
        this.back();
        return new JSONException(message + " around this char: '" + this.next() + "' " + this.toString());
    }
}

HttpStream httpStream = new HttpStream(new URI(VarGlobais.url + "/descarga/listDescarga"), options);

if (httpStream.isOk()) {

    byte[] BUFF = new byte[2048];
    int read = httpStream.readBytes(BUFF, 0, BUFF.length);
    String firstBytes = new String(BUFF, 0, read);

    JSONObject teste = new JSONObject(new JsonTokenerTest(firstBytes));

    [...]
}
```

Comment: Jefferson, nesse exemplo que passei, teria algum problema se eu usasse o método httpStream.readLine() em vez de criar o array de bytes e ler baseado no tamanho desse array? Porque já que a quantidade de registro vinda do webservice é variável, pode ser que o tamanho que eu coloque não seja o suficiente para ler a linha.

Comment: @DeivisonCardoso, o ideal é ler a stream inteira =) Se você acha que o retorno do WebService pode vir a ser muito grande, recomendo fortemente ir atrás da solução SAX; caso contrário (retorno razoavelmente gerenciável), é possível ler todo o conteúdo em memória. Fizemos uma [classe de wrapper sobre HttpStream](https://github.com/TotalCross/tc-utilities/blob/master/src/main/java/com/tc/utils/utilities/io/HttpConn.java) que pode te ajudar. Vou atualizar minha resposta em breve com considerações a respeito do tamanho dos dados e como lidar com isso